# I have a mistake in my one-line ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to put 2 watermarks on a video:

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -i big.jpg -i all.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='between(t,0,1)' ; overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" "output\%%~na.mp4"
```

But I receive an error:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the overlay filters which inputs to use:

```
for %%i in (.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -i big.jpg -i all.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='between(t,0,1)'[bg];[bg][2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" "output\%%~na.mp4"
```